# Export Library path & include in perl

Tags: perl, include, export

I have a query with regards to exporting library path & include for Platypus variant caller. The htslib it requires and platypus are installed on the server and I don't have sudo permissions to change them.

I am trying the following code to export library & include for running the caller. Am i missing osmething because am not able to execute it?

Code:

```
#!usr/perl-w
use strict;
use warnings;

`export LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/htslib/lib/`;
`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/htslib/lib/`;
`export INCLUDE_PATH=/opt/htslib/include/`;
system ("python /opt/Platypus_0.8.1/Platypus.py callVariants --help");
```

Any sort of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You're setting the env vars of freshly-made shells, not of the Perl process that is to parent `python`. For that, you need the following:

```
$ENV{LIBRARY_PATH} = '/opt/htslib/lib/';
$ENV{LD_LIBRARY_PATH} = '/opt/htslib/lib/';
$ENV{INCLUDE_PATH} = '/opt/htslib/include/';
```

The last line of your code is better written as follows, since it avoids a needless shell:

```
system("python", "/opt/Platypus_0.8.1/Platypus.py", "callVariants", "--help");
```

Comment: Maybe add that those freshly-made shells are immediately discarded.

Comment: Many thanks. It worked although the python command in system within the single quote also works fine. So am not lcear about the shell you mentioned about.

Comment: I'm talking about the shells spawned to executed your shell commands. How do you think the shell command you pass to `system` gets executed? `system($shell_cmd)` is short for `system('sh', '-c', $shell_command)`. It's a waste, and a potential source of problem. it makes it easy to add shell injection vulnerabilities. It complicates signaling, and it prevents you from accurately determining how `python` exited. So no, it's not fine; it's adequate at best.